# What does the i--> opeator do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So I took a look at the code that controls the counter on the SO advertising page. Then I saw the line where this occured `i-->`. What does this do?

Here is the full code:

```
$(function(){

    var visitors = 5373891;
    var updateVisitors = function()
    {
            visitors++;

            var vs = visitors.toString(), 
                 i = Math.floor(vs.length / 3),
                 l = vs.length % 3;
            while (i-->0) if (!(l==0&&i==0))          // <-------- Here it is!!!
                vs = vs.slice(0,i*3+l)
                   + ',' 
                   + vs.slice(i*3+l);
            $('#devCount').text(vs);
            setTimeout(updateVisitors, Math.random()*2000);
    };

    setTimeout(updateVisitors, Math.random()*2000);

});
```

Comment: This is obviously copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: This question is about Javascript. The one you reference is about C/C++. It's true they are similar, and possibly even copied, but I think this is a fair enough variant since it asks about a different language.

Comment: @Rob Levine: Great!, I'll post a similar question for every programming language that supports both the post decrement operator and the greater than operator :-P (and for every language that supports pre decrement and less than operators xD)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/194544

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`i-->0` is the same as `i-- > 0`, so the comparison expression if the evaluated value of `i--` is greater than `0`.

Comment: Wow, running it all together like that even confused me for a moment there. Good eye, Gumbo.

Comment: That seems really messy! Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: Just to clarify, means that the comparison "i > 0" occurs *before* i is decremented.

Comment: @RobertPitt - No, not really.

Comment: @RobertPitt: It’s more like `(i=i-1) > 0`.

Answer (score 6):

it is not an operator. See this link:

[What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

```
var i = 10;

while (i-- > 0)
{
   alert('i = ' + i);
}
```

Output:

```
i = 9 
i = 8 
i = 7 
i = 6 
i = 5 
i = 4 
i = 3 
i = 2 
i = 1 
i = 0
```

Comment: Did you mix C# with your Java? ;-)

Comment: At first i thought that i wrote the javascript code wrong :) You mean the avatar. Yes I migrated C# from Java and i love coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have explained that it's two operators. I'll just add that in the example, it's unnecessary. If you're counting down from a positive integer to zero, you can miss out the greater-than-zero test and your code will be shorter and, I think, clearer:

```
var i = 10;
while (i--) {
    // Do stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought of the exact same thread that JCasso thought of.
[What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)

I think this code style stems from the early days of programming when terminals had limited display real estate.

Comment: No, it's quite a new trend. It's syntactic sugar that reads `while i approaches zero`. Some people like it. Some just gets confused. It really depends on weather you've gotten used to seeing it or not. Kinda like regular expressions: when you first see it you want to vomit violently onto the keyboard, then you grow to love it.

Comment: Ahh ok, you learn something new everyday. I'm not a huge fan of it I have to admit i-- > 0 reads better to me.

Comment: I appreciate the `-->` operator, but no number of years of regex use has stopped me vomiting :-)