# What does while (i --> 0) mean?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, operators

I apologize if this a stupid question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

How does the following code work? (I realize that it loops over the elements of `els`)

```
var i = els.length;
while (i --> 0) {
    var el = els[i];
    // ...do stuff...
}
```

I have no idea what `-->` means. There is no documentation for it. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: It's i-- greater than 0

Comment: A spacing typo really got 4 upvotes?

Comment: @RUJordan - It's not a spacing typo. It's (probably) a deliberate attempt to form an arrow with `-->` as a kind of pseudo "count down" operator. The whole statement to be read as "i goes to zero"...

Comment: @nnnnnn Now that I know what it does, I agree that it's probably meant to just be humorous/annoying.

Comment: Just using `while(i--)` is enough.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Kind of obfuscates the code a little bit

Comment: @nderscore: That's a little different. In cases where you don't have a guarantee that `i` starts off `>= 0`, the loop could  continue.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not a c++ pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the i--> opeator do in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034848/what-does-the-i-opeator-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be read as

```
i-- > 0
```

So, what really happens is,

1. value of `i` will be checked if it greater than 0, if it is true then control will enter the `while` block, if it is false `while` block will be skipped.
2. Either way, the value of `i` will be decremented, **immediately** after the condition is checked.

Its always better to use `for` loop, when we run a loop with a counter, like this

```
for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    ...
}
```

[Please read more about whether `++`, `--` is okay or not.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/971312/1903116)

Comment: The value is checked on the value before the decrement. If it was written as `--i > 0` then the value would be checked after the decrement.

Comment: @Cuberto Thats why I mentioned post decremented. :)

Comment: You did mention "post decremented", but you confused it by saying "and then the value will be checked", which makes it sound like that happens after decrementing...

Comment: So it's like `i - 1 > 0`?

Comment: @ManofSnow `i - 1` will not actually change the value of `i`, `i--` will change the value of `i`.

Answer (score 7):

It's just weird spacing, should be

```
while((i--) > 0)
```

it's just post-decrementing and checking the condition.
There was this humorous answer at the [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator?rq=1) question, but I think it got deleted

```
while (x --\
            \
             \
              \
               > 0) //i goes down to zero!
```

Or something like that, anyway

So if you had something like

```
var i=3;
while(i-->0){
     console.log(i);
}
```

it would return

```
2
1
0
```

Comment: it's SO ;-) But anyway, your answer shared such a funny C++ piece of code which worth upvoting )

Comment: lol... I just read the original answer and the comments followed it.

Comment: Yeah I think I read all of the answers and comments there at least once

Answer (score 1):

The code should actually be:

```
while (i-- > 0) {
```

where the loop will run if the value after the variable `i` has been decremented is greater than zero.

Comment: The decrement occurs after comparison, `--i` is pre–decrement.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (i--> 0) 
{
    // ...do stuff
}
```

**is same as**

```
while (i>0) 
{
     i--;    
    // ...do stuff
}
```

IMHO we should write simple code rather than clever code because it's not understandable by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's just weird spacing.  It's same as

```
while (i--  >  0) {
```